# Info about the active client connections in an Azure Redis Cluster

Tags: azure, azure-redis-cache

I am new to Azure and was trying to understand if I could use Azure Redis in my application.

Assuming, the application to run at a decent scale(currently don't have the exact numbers), my main point to ask this question is, as per the pricing [tier](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cache/) of Azure, it says Premium supports upto 40k client connections. Now, is this connection count per node of the cluster or for the total cluster itself?

Answer (score 0):

It is per node, by default you get no cluster and to have more nodes you will enable clustering when you are creating your premium Azure Redis cache instance. Please take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-planning-faq#azure-cache-for-redis-performance) for a detailed look per shard or per node in a cluster in the premium tier. If you are expecting load but you do not have one right now then I would recommend to start with Standard tier now and when the need arises upgrade to Premium but remember you cannot scale back to Standard then and you get clustering only if you create the Azure Redis cache resource with Premium and enable clustering while creating it. But you get HA built with both Standard and Premium tiers but Redis Enterprise features are only available with the Premium tier.